# Dynamically pick values from req.body based on database attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am building an app usine Node/EJS/Mongo where the user is building a capability survey, and needs to set the desired level for each question. The form that they use to pick the levels has a series of selects that look like:

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-4" id="<%=capability.capabilityId%>" name="<%=capability.capabilityId%>">
   <option value=1>Developing</option>
   <option value=2>Intermediate</option>
   <option value=3>Advanced</option>
   <option value=4>Role Model</option>
</select>
```

When the user then submits this form, I want to update the assessment to load in these expected levels.

The schema for assessments in my mongodb looks like:

```
var assessmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  title: String,
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  behaviours: [{
    behaviourName: String,
    behaviourId: String,
    order: Number,
    capabilities: [{
      orderCap: Number,
      capabilityId: String,
      capabilityName: String,
      capabilityDesc: String,
      developing: String,
      intermediate: String,
      advanced: String,
      roleModel: String,
      expectedLevel: Number,
      motivation1: String,
      motivation2: String,
      motivation3: String,
      motivation4: String,
      motivation5: String
    }]   //capabilities object
  }],
  targetEmployees:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Users"
  }]  //behaviours object
});
```

What I am thinking is I want to loop through all the capabilities, find the entry in `req.body` that has a name that matches `capabilityId`, and then update `desiredLevel`. I just can't see how to make it work. My route code currently looks like:

```
router.put(':id/levels', function(req, res) {
  Assessment.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundAssessment) {
    foundAssessment.behaviours.forEach(function(b) {
      b.capabilities.forEach(function(c) {
        c.expectedLevel = req.body.SOMETHINGHERE
      });
    });

    foundAssessment.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash("error", err.message);
        res.redirect("back");
      } else {
        // Send json back to xhr request
        res.json(foundAssessment);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read request body dynamic attributes like this:

```
req.body[variable];
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you so much